# Solver lbfgs supports only 'l2' or 'none' penalties, got l1 penalty

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I'm building a logistic regression model to predict a binary target feature. I want to try different values of different parameters using the `param_grid` argument, to find the best fit with the best values. This is my code:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.25, random_state = 42)

logModel = LogisticRegression(C = 1, penalty='l1',solver='liblinear');

Grid_params = {
    "penalty" : ['l1','l2','elasticnet','none'],
    "C" : [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000], # Basically smaller C specify stronger regularization.
    'solver' : ['lbfgs','newton-cg','liblinear','sag','saga'],
    'max_iter' : [50,100,200,500,1000,2500]
    
}

clf = GridSearchCV(logModel, param_grid=Grid_params, cv = 10, verbose = True, n_jobs=-1,error_score='raise')

clf_fitted = clf.fit(X_train,Y_train)
```

And this is where I get the error. I have read already that some `solvers` dont work with `l1`, and some don't work with `l2`. How can I tune the `param_grid` in this case?

I tried also using only simple `logModel = LogisticRegression()` but didn't work.

Full error:

```
ValueError: Solver lbfgs supports only 'l2' or 'none' penalties, got l1 penalty.
```

Comment: FWIW, including the `solver` in a parameter grid sounds quite awkward...

Comment: Well, to be honest I didn't realy understand what a solver is in the first place, but all tutorials included it in the grid, so I did too. Why do you think it's awkward?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gridsearch accepts the list of dicts for that purpose, given you absolutely need to include solvers into grid, you should be able to do something like this:

```
Grid_params  = [
    {'solver' : ['saga'],
      'penalty' : ['elasticnet', 'l1', 'l2', 'none'],
      'max_iter' : [50,100,200,500,1000,2500],
      'C' : [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000]},
    {'solver' : ['newton-cg', 'lbfgs'],
      'penalty' : ['l2','none'],
      'max_iter' : [50,100,200,500,1000,2500],
      'C' : [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000]},
     # add more parameter sets as needed...
    ]
```